# SWIFTUI How to capture VStack height with geometry (after the VStack was displayed)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, screen, vstack

I'd like to ask you some help. I'm trying to capture **VStack height** using **geometry** and then based on that **VStack height** value, calculate its child element's height (inside VStack).

[Image of my current view of VStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njast.png)

I used **.frame** outside of VStack to fill the whole screen. Then I used **.borde**r to visually check if it actually fills the screen **(it works fine)**

`.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)`

The problem can be seen inside the VStack, the height is displayed as GCFloat 734. Even though the border size is **a lot bigger**.

```
struct BodyView: View {
    @State var stackHeight : CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("VStack size: \(self.stackHeight)")
                    .bold()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background(Color.green)

            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
            .onAppear{
                self.stackHeight = geometry.size.height
            }
            .border(Color.purple, width: 5)
        }
    }
}

struct BodyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BodyView()
    }
}
```

How could I capture the actual size of the VStack when it finishes loading?
When I trigger (onAppear) the VStack height appears correct, however I need it to be captured instantly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get CGRect of View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214625/get-cgrect-of-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your questions, you're very close — you just need to use to [`GeometryProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy) type:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BodyView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("VStack size: \(geometry.size.height)") // no need for state var anymore
                    .bold()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
            .border(Color.purple, width: 5)
        }
    }
}

struct BodyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BodyView()
    }
}
```

A `GeometryReader` will lay itself out again if its size changes.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day. It works fine now & it so clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use geometry reader with background to get right height.

```
VStack {
    yourContent
}
.background {
   GeometryReader { reader in
       Color.clear
       .onChange(of: reader.size.height) { newVal
            heightStateVariable = newVal
       }
       .onAppear {
            heightStateVariable = proxy.size.height
       }
   }
}
```

In SwiftUI .background content takes space as per VStack content (upon which background modifier applied - some exceptions are there)