# SwiftUI TextField takes max width

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a navigation list with each list item being in this format:

```
HStack {
        TextField("Insert something here.",text: self.$userData.pages[i].title)
            .border(Color.blue)
        Spacer()
    }
```

This results in the following view:

[The touchable area is highlighted by the blue border and it takes the whole width of the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90J6Q.png)

The problem with this is that despite the list item being a navigation link, the user clicking anywhere along the item will result in them editing the text content. What I would prefer is a `TextField` that has the same width as a `Text`:

[The blue border wraps the text instead of taking the max width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7QB0.png)

So if the user clicks outside the `TextField`, the navigation works, but if they click *on* the text, it will let them edit the text. (The above view is with `Text` field).

Apologies if I've asked an unclear or bad question. I'm new to Stack Overflow and SwiftUI.

Edit:

I've tried using the `fixedSize` modifier, and the TextField correctly wraps my Text, but now the Navigation Link doesn't work (i.e. clicking on it just doesn't navigate). This is my full code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: PageView(page: self.userData.pages[i])) {
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {}){
                                TextField(" ", text: self.$userData.pages[i].title)
                                .fixedSize()

                            }
                            .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
                            .border(Color.blue)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This should be helpful [Make TextField wrap it content in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821548/12299030)

Comment: @Asperi I've tried this, and I believe it runs into the same issue I described in my edit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No need to apologize, your question is clear.
You can do this by using `fixedSize()`

so your code should be like this

```
HStack {
        TextField("Insert something here.",text: self.$userData.pages[i].title)
            .border(Color.blue)
            .fixedSize()
        Spacer()
    }
```

You can further specify how would you like the stretch to be, either `vertical` or `horizontal` or even both by passing parameters like so
`.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)`

**UPDATED ANSWER TO MATCH YOUR NEW REQUIREMENTS**

```
import SwiftUI

struct StackOverflow5: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Page2(), tag: 1, selection:self.$selection) {
                    Color.clear
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.selection = 1
                        }
                }


                TextField("Text", text: self.$text)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StackOverflow5_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackOverflow5()
    }
}

struct Page2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Page2")
    }
}
```

We used a `ZStack` here to separate between our `TextField` and our `NavigationLink` so they can be interacted with separately.

Note the use of `Color.clear` before our `TextField` and this is on purpose so that our `TextField` has interaction priority. Also we used Color.clear because it will stretch as a background and it's `clear` so it's not visible.

Obviously I hard coded `1` here but this can be from `List` or a `ForEach`

Additionally, if you don't want to use `selection` and `tag` you can do something like this

```
...
@State var isActive: Bool = false
...
NavigationLink(destination: Page2(), isActive: self.$isActive) {
     Color.clear
          .onTapGesture {
               self.isActive.toggle()
          }
}
....
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I guess I ignored `fixedSize` when going through the documentation bc it said it fixed the view at its ideal size, and I thought that meant the same thing as its default size.

Comment: No worries, glad I was able to help. Keep in mind though `fixedSize` is a function of any view not necessarily `TextField`. Good luck!

Comment: So I've just tried this, and I've run into a problem, although I'm not sure if this is this solution's fault, but now the NavigationLink just doesn't seem to work. I know the TextField is being properly wrapped, but clicking on the row does not navigate me. I tried the simulator and the real device, but it still doesn't seem to work. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Got it, I am working on updating my answer to reflect. Are you okay with fixed width and height? because one solution is to wrap everything in a `zStack` so that NavigationLink sits under textfield and it takes 100% width and 100% height, this way if you tap on NavigationLink you are good and if you tap on textfield, well you oonly update textfield.

Comment: Are you referring to fixed width/height of the NavigationLink or the TextField? I need the TextField to take the width of the text inside it but the navigationLink's width/height can be fixed.

Comment: So it turns out something else in my code was actually the culprit for breaking the navigation link...I apologize for the inconvenience I caused! I tried your updated code and the original code after fixing it and both work. Sorry about that again (still new to Swift...). Thanks so much!

Comment: Not a problem at all! don't hesitate to ask if you need more help!