# can I get the tap position over a Text View?

Tags: swiftui

a Text view is like:

```
Text("hello world")
.onTapGesture{
...}
```

can I get the tab position ,so that to infer which word is tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach how to get tap location in `Text` view coordinate space:

```
Text("hello world")
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded { value in
    print("Position: \(value.location)") // in local coordinates
})
```

Comment: Can I get the width of the Text View then?

Comment: @龙方哲, [Get CGRect of View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214735/12299030)