# SwiftUI: pass view information to UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uialertcontroller, uihostingcontroller

I have a UIKit and AppKit app, and I am displaying a SwiftUI view within it via UIHostingController / NSHostingController. The view has some buttons on it, and I want to pass back the tap event back to a UIKit/AppKit view controller to show UIAlertController from the button that got tapped (I would prefer to use ActionSheet within SwiftUI but it isn't supported on macOS). I pass a delegate through the hosting controller into the SwiftUI view, and use that to call back into the UIKit/AppKit view. But to display a UIAlertController (or even `UIActivityViewController`), I would need to get some information about the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` from the SwiftUI view, else it might crash on iPad.

How do I pass back that information, from the SwiftUI view into the UIKit/Appkit app? I guess the `sourceView` could be the SwiftUI view on display, but how do I read (and pass back) the rect of the SwiftUI  button that was tapped?

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214735/12299030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. Since the button is a few layers of subviews down from the top-level SwiftUI, I gave that parent view a 'name', by using:

```
.coordinateSpace(name: "CalloutParentView")
```

Then I wrapped the button in a `GeometryReader`, and in the button handler, I got the 'rect' by using:

```
geometry.frame(in: .named("ParentView")
```

I passed that through the delegate to the hosting UIViewController, and that can         use the SwiftUI view as the `sourceView` and this rect as the `sourceRect`